# How can i compare two datetimes in Django

Tags: django

I can`t compare two datetime variable. One of it is DateTimeField in my models.py

```
date_of_end_discount = models.DateTimeField()
```

Second is datetime.now. This is sample of code of compare

```
from datetime import datetime

def is_discount(self):
    return self.date_of_end_discount > datetime.now()
```

But i have TypeError:

```
can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

Comment: just try datetime.datetime.now()

Comment: Check the format of both, in which format date_of_end_discount is exactly stored?

Comment: DateTimeField is offset-naive and datetime.now() is offset-aware, both of them is datetime type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK datetime.now() is not timezone aware.

Django comes with a helper for this, which requires pytz

```
 naive = datetime.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

or you can use timezone instead of datetime to fix this issue.

```
from django.utils import timezone
now = timezone.now()
```

You should be able to compare your dates now.

Comment: Thanks, you are help me very much!